# How to fix ‘Path Manipulation’ issue from Fortify scan report for tthe following code sample

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have path Manipulation problem. The following code is placed in Page_load method of ASPx page.

```
String rName = Request.QueryString["reportName"];
string path = "C:\\hari" + rName;
if (File.Exists(path))
{
    File.Delete(path);
}
```

But Fortify scan report for the above sample code shows ‘Path Manipulation’  issue as high 
Need help to modify above code so that it can pass fortify scan

Answer (score 6):

Jackson is right, this is a direct File Path Manipulation vulnerability that can be fixed through indirect selection.
From your known directory, list all the files. Use the value coming from your own directory list, not the user-supplied value.

```
String rName = Request.QueryString["reportName"];
String knownPath = "C:\\hari";
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(knownPath);
FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles(rName);

if (files.length > 0)
{
    files[0].Delete();
}
```

Comment: how about if we are trying open the existing file?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that someone could spoof a request with `reportName = "..\\Windows\\Something important"` which is clearly a security flaw. You need to change your code so that it doesn't read a partial filename from the request query string.

Comment: could you plz  provide what changes required for the above code

Comment: Not without more information. What are you trying to do with this webpage?

Comment: it just a sample web page. the example which i gave in this Q is a sample . if i get my ans then i can use same logic to fix my problem in other application