# .NET Fortify Path Manipulation

Tags: c#, .net, fortify, path-manipulation

Does anyone know how to resolve path manipulation issue reported by Forify scan.

I am already checking it path is exists but still Fortify reporting it as a vulnerability.
Example:

```
string path = "set by user";
if(Path.Exists(path))
{
//Do file upload
}
```

Comment: Possible Duplicate of:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4732967/how-to-fix-path-manipulation-issue-from-fortify-scan-report-for-tthe-following